# Ubuntu Server won't upload files with PHP 'move_uploaded_file'

Tags: php, file-upload, ubuntu, permissions

I'm trying to upload files using my Ubuntu Virtual Server.

The PHP function moving the uploaded files returns the following error:

> "Warning: move_uploaded_file(files/Site Logo.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test.php on line 5 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpZB7Mxi' to 'files/Site Logo.png' in /var/www/test.php on line 5"

The directory has permissions `0777` which I set through the SSH and it still doesn't upload. PHP.ini is configured to `upload ON` and stuff but no luck. I'd guess its permissions problems but I have set it to pretty much `RWX` for every user?

My code originally was too complex for a video system so I tried a basic code like below:

```
$file = $_FILES['video']['name'];
echo $file;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'],"files/".$file);
echo "Done";
```

This wouldn't work either. So I am guessing it's how the server is configured?

Comment: have you tried using absolute paths i.e. /var/www/files/

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same problem, it was permission problem. Just

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/work_pathname/the_upload_pathname/*
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check:

- You did check the permissions on files/ using ls -l?
- Did you run
  chmod 777 /var/www without the -R flag?

Still sounds like a permissions error, something small you might have missed...